# Alamofire Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 error occurs after upgrade El Capitan with Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using Alamofire 2.0.1 (latest update) and SwiftyJSON for call rest api to my server. But today, after upgrade El Capitan and Xcode 7.0.1, suddenly "Alamofire Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2" <- error occurred
. Some people have same issue like me, but that's all there was no answer for that.

Here is my code and it goes .Failure case and spit error.

I hope somebody solves this problem :(

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(kServerUrl)/rest/report/createAccessLog", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON
            { _, _, result in
                switch result {
                case .Success(let data):
                    var json = JSON(data)
                    if let header = json["header"]["returnCode"].number where header==0 {
                    } else {
                    }
                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    print("something wrong with fetch createAccessLog \(error)")
                }
        }
```

Comment: May not be it but are you using HTTPS?

Comment: No I'm on the test with my local server. Could it be possible because of firewall? kServerUrl was http://111.1.1.11(for instance). And I tried to change it as http://localhost and it suddenly works well. I'm so confusing for that

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: I solvedthis issue but Im not sure why. In my case, it's because of network status. I changed the ip address in different way then it works as normal

Comment: Same issue here, what change did you make to that address ip @jamesBlake ?

Comment: Current workaround is to download ios simulator v8.4. It works with my local server.

Comment: @jamesBlake thanx! switching to localhost seemed to work great for me. Must be something with the firewall, Didn't try the iOS simulator yet but i assume that would work too. There is also a new update for xcode today, which maybe fixes it too

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem,I have resolved it by apple release Notes.
apple release Notes:When running in an iOS simulator for iOS versions 9.1 and earlier, an app may not communicate with TCP/IP services hosted locally by the Mac using the Mac’s local IP address.
Connect via a loopback address, such as localhost or 127.0.0.1. (22453539).[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)
you just use 127.0.0.1 instead of Mac’s local IP address.

Comment: Made my day, mate. Sheesh i cant stand apple some times.